# EmailMessage cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: emailmessage

I am a beginner in using Salesforce API with SOAP. My goal is to send an email that will be then shown as "Sent" in Salesforce.com user interface.

I am able to send an email using [SingleEmailMessage](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_sendemail.htm) but this one doesn't offer me the possibility to set the email as "Sent", it will be shown as "New" instead.
I figured out that instead of using SingleEmailMessage object I should use [EmailMessage](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_send_email_message.htm) object that allows to manipulate the status of the email (New,Sent,Draft, etc) and I believe the status = 3 is what I need.

I followed the above EmailMessage example for java  but  compilation fails with type error "EmailMessage cannot be resolved to a type"

My code (mostly copied from the example) looks as follows

```
package com;

import com.sforce.soap.partner.*;  
import com.sforce.soap.partner.sobject.*;  
import com.sforce.ws.*;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

   try {

       // make connection

        ConnectorConfig config = new ConnectorConfig();
        config.setUsername("***");
        config.setPassword("***");
        PartnerConnection connection = null;
        // create a connection object with the credentials
        connection = Connector.newConnection(config);

       String caseId = "5006000000jrPkQAAU";

      //Create a draft EmailMessage
      EmailMessage message = new EmailMessage(); <-- EmailMessage cannot be resolved to a type

      (...)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: any tiny hint would be appreciated...